# How can I take non-ASCII strings from an Excel cell and place them into a text file (JSON format) with proper encoding?

Tags: excel, vba, unicode

We are writing a very basic macro for an Excel file that takes values from cells and places them into a text file with a JSON format. We are using the `Range` function to extract the cell values like this:

```
Print #iFile, "          ""title"": """ & Range("AP" & cell.Row).Value & """"
```

I'm sure this isn't the prettiest or most efficient approach, but it seems to work for our purposes (and to be perfectly honest, we don't have anyone on hand that is actually a VBA developer really...). The problem, though, is when we encounter foreign characters (Latin, Japanese, etc) that are not being picked up by the VBA code above whatsoever.

What we would like to do is not only extract the string from the cell no matter what type of characters are in there (ASCII or otherwise), and place them into the text file with any necessary encoding on the string values such that the file will still contain valid JSON.

Any help with this issue would be very appreciated as this is a subject that is far out of my comfort zone (front-end web development).

Answer (score 0):

This should get you headed in the right direction

```
Public Sub SaveUnicodeCharacterInTextFile()
' Declare a FileSystemObject.
Dim fso As FileSystemObject
' Create a FileSystemObject.
Set fso = New FileSystemObject
' Declare a TextStream.
Dim stream As TextStream
' windows path name
wbPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
' name the output file and path to save it to - same directory as the workbook
outFile = wbPath & "\outputfile.txt"
' Create a TextStream. Overwrite = true Unicode = True
Set stream = fso.CreateTextFile(outFile, True, True)
'Put a value in the stream - in this case we are simly pulling the value out of one cell
'You can certainly iterate through the worksheet
stream.Write (Range("A1"))
'close the stream
stream.Close
End Sub
```